# CKEditor add <p> Tag in empty divs

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x, rte

when i add this in my CKEditor it writes it in the database just fine:

```
<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xAaNCUj0sI">
<div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%;"><iframe allow="encrypted-media; accelerometer; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5xAaNCUj0sI?rel=0" style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" tabindex="-1"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

but when i reloade the backend it opens it like this:

```
<p> </p>

<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xAaNCUj0sI">
<div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
<p> </p>
<iframe allow="encrypted-media; accelerometer; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5xAaNCUj0sI?rel=0" style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" tabindex="-1"></iframe>

<p> </p>
</div>

<p> </p>
</div>

<p> </p>
```

How can i stop CKEditor to add these

to empty divs...

Hope some can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out adding `DIV`

to:

```
RTE.default.proc.blockElementList = PRE,UL,OL,H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,ADDRESS,DL,DD,HEADER,SECTION,FOOTER,NAV,ARTICLE,ASIDE,IFRAME,DIV
```

in the page.ts fixes it.